# How to add new rules in Kohana framework

Tags: php, kohana

I'm using Kohana framework for my project development, I need to introduce new rules Suppose I have original_price and discount_price fields, for this discount_price must be always always less than or equal to original_price.

For this scenario, how to write new rule(method).

Comment: Which version of Kohana are you using?

Comment: `original_price` and `discount_price` are properties of a model?

Comment: I encourage you to use the latest ,Would it be much better if you'd use the latest, you would get more support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Kohana framework,you will find `validation.php` file,in that write a appropriate validation function.Suppose you want to test some length of a text field then write relevant function here and call that function in your controller class using add_rules().I hope you got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use v3.2 and check this page out: http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/validation